# Disable network connections on Windows 8.1 startup

Tags: networking, windows-8.1

How can I configure Win8.1 to start with all network connections disabled and then be able to re-enable them afterwards on demand?

Comment: Have you tried writting a Power Shell script to do this?

Comment: No, I haven't. I don't have any expertise with Power Shell.